# Querying SQLPlus from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sqlplus

I'm working on a system that consists of:

- Database (using Oracle's SQLPlus)
- Web form (ASP.net using C# on Visual Studio)

I established a successful connection between the SQLPlus database and Visual Studio. I created a simple form to test if I can query SQLPlus via this web form.

My question: what "using" statements should I add for this situation (SQLPlus)?
I should also mention that I used SQL server with Visual Studio before, but I had to switch to SQLPlus.

If anyone can link me an article about using SQLPlus with Visual Studio that would be great too.

Installed Programs: Oracle Database 12c, Visual Studio 2015, Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.

Comment: what do you really mean with sqlplus? SQLPlus is a command line tool to access Oracle databases.
Are you asking about how to get access to Oracle database programmatically?

Comment: we have everything you need to do your .NET stuff with Oracle just like you did before with SQL Server http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/microsoft/overview/index.html

Comment: You don't "query SQLPlus". You _use_ sqlplus to query an Oracle database.